# How to delete an element from google datastore as well as my html page using delete method?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-datastore

Iam currently using flask and google datastore and working on it

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_task(task_id):
    pass
return jsonify({'result': True})
```

Ive used get and post and also put method for inserting retrieving and updating now i need to delete using delete request

I tried to pass the respective id value by using href in my html page but I found it doesnt work that way !

Comment: Show us exactly what you tried and what didn't work means https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem is with flask or with Cloud Datastore.  However, for Cloud Datastore, you'll want to create a key for the entity you want to delete, then pass that key to the delete method.  The details are at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-delete-python .

Comment: Thank you @JimMorrison the code now works perfect but only through get request ....Can we delete that entity using delete request?



`@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['DELETE','GET'])
def delete_task(task_id):`
 `k = ndb.Key('ToDo',(task_id))
 k.delete()
 return redirect(url_for('task'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def delete_method(task_id):
    k = ndb.Key('ToDo', task_id)
    k.delete()
    return jsonify({"success":True})
```

The above code works fine and the ajax request is as follows

```
function delData(){
    var id = this.id
    //console.log(id)
    var url = '/DELETE/todo/api/v1.0/task/';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("DELETE", url+id, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
            console.log(jsonResponse);
            var elem = document.getElementById(id).parentNode;
            while (elem.firstChild) {
                elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
                }
            }
        else {
            console.error(jsonResponse);
        }
}
xhr.send(null);
}
```